# HttpUrlConnection.getContentLength() returns -1 but the header field exists

Tags: java, php, httpurlconnection

I'm experiencing a strange behavior of my Java application which download files from a Web server. I download APK files or bash scripts. Both are served the same way by the server but when I download a bash script, the getContentLength() method returns the right content length and when I download an APK file, the method returns -1...

Here is the PHP function I use to serve the files :

```
function send_file($file) {

    header('Content-Type: application/force-download; name="' . basename($file) . '"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    readfile($file);
    exit();

}
```

And the Java code to download the files :

```
URL requestUrl = new URL("http://download.myesmart.net/api.php?id=" + Tablet.ID + "&type=" + type);

// Start the connection to the server
if ((connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection()) == null) {

    Log.d("TAG", "Impossible to contact the server.");
    return null;

}

connection.connect();

// Check the HTTP code
if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

    Log.d("TAG", "Bad server response : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
    return null;

}

// Return -1 sometimes...
Log.d("TAG", "Content-Length : " + connection.getContentLength());
```

If I check the HTTP header fields this Web tool : http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php, I get the same response type but the first works and the second doesn't.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Set-Cookie => mailplan=R243416773; path=/; expires=Thu, 13-Nov-2014 09:19:48 GMT
Content-Type => application/force-download; name="configure-keyboard.sh"
Server => Apache
Content-Transfer-Encoding => binary
Content-Disposition => attachment; filename="configure-keyboard.sh"
Expires => 0
Cache-Control => no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma => no-cache
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Date => Thu, 13 Nov 2014 08:19:39 GMT
Connection => close
X-Geo => varn16.rbx5
X-Geo-Port => 1015
X-Cacheable => Not cacheable: no-cache
Content-Length => 1118

HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Set-Cookie => mailplan=R1918955109; path=/; expires=Thu, 13-Nov-2014 08:59:12 GMT
Content-Type => application/force-download; name="InfoConfort_20141102_ec_v1dev.apk"
Server => Apache
Content-Transfer-Encoding => binary
Content-Disposition => attachment; filename="InfoConfort_20141102_ec_v1dev.apk"
Expires => 0
Cache-Control => no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma => no-cache
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Date => Thu, 13 Nov 2014 07:53:43 GMT
Connection => close
X-Geo => varn16.rbx5
X-Geo-Port => 1015
X-Cacheable => Not cacheable: no-cache
Content-Length => 5149910
```

Any idea ???

Answer (score 0):

According to JavaDocs getContentLength method returns -1, if content length is not known yet.

Would you mind to try this:

```
URL requestUrl = new URL("http://download.myesmart.net/api.php?id=" + Tablet.ID + "&type=" + type);

//Start the connection to the server
if ((connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection()) == null) {

 Log.d("TAG", "Impossible to contact the server.");
 return null;

}   
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity")
Log.d("TAG", "Content-Length : " + connection.getContentLength());
```

**edited.**

Comment: IOException : Connection already established
Impossible to contact the server.